# What is the proper way to port index from solr 4 to solr 6?

Tags: solr

My current solr version is 4.10.3. I am about to upgrade to solr 6.x. However, i have more than 36 GB index in my current version. How can i port this data to solr 6 and make it compatible with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'll have to go through `5.x` as well.

The easiest way is to use [Jan Høiberg's shellscript](https://github.com/cominvent/solr-tools/tree/master/upgradeindex) that automagically upgrades a `4.x` index to `6.x` (or a future `7.x`) index format.

It'll fetch the library for each major version of Solr and run the index upgrade to that version, before moving on to the next version and doing the same.